Loss becomes Nan after attention_mask is added to the model while fine-tuning gemma2
I was trying to fine-tune gemma2 2b model on my own dataset for sequence classification tasks. But when I was testing the model, I found that after I plugged in the attention_mask to the model, the loss becomes Nan.
Here is my code
from peft import get_peft_model, LoraConfig, TaskType
from transformers import (AutoTokenizer,Gemma2ForSequenceClassification,DataCollatorWithPadding)
import torch

temp = Gemma2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
"gemma2b",device_map="auto",torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS,
    inference_mode=False,
    r=8,
    lora_alpha=32,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    target_modules=['down_proj','o_proj','k_proj','q_proj','gate_proj','up_proj','v_proj']
)

model = get_peft_model(temp, peft_config)
model.print_trainable_parameters()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gemma2b")

label=torch.tensor([0]).to('cuda')

raw_t=tokenizer(['I like it too'],return_tensors='pt',padding='max_length',max_length=10).to('cuda')
 
print(model(input_ids=raw_t.input_ids ,attention_mask=raw_t.attention_mask ,labels=label))

Ane here is the output:
SequenceClassifierOutputWithPast(loss=tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>), logits=tensor([[nan, nan]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16,grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>), past_key_values=None, hidden_states=None, attentions=None)

If I don't plug in the attention_mask, the loss looks fine.
Besides, I noticed that if I don't pad the input to the max_length(attention_mask is all 1s), the problem won't occur.
And if I change the precision to float16, the loss seems normal too.
Could anyone help me solve the problem?

This is the problem of the default attention.
Applying flash attention could solve this:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/32390
